# energy conservative surface average

Tags: algorithms, average, surface-integrals, discrete-optimization, numerical-calculus

first of all, thanks for the help you guys provide! My question is the following: I have one power load $q^*$ [W/$m^2$] (a scalar) defined over a triangle $\mathcal{T}^*$ of surface $A^*$. My target is to compute the surface average over the set $\{\mathcal{T}_j\}_{j=1}^N$ which contains $\mathcal{T}^*$ itself and other $(N-1)$ neighboring triangles (neighbor = triangle which shares at least one vertex with the reference ($^*$) one), each one with its power load $q_j$. The result is then assigned to $\mathcal{T}^*$. To do so, I relied on the formula:

\begin{equation}
\overline{q}^* = \frac{1}{A} \iint_{A}q(x,y,z) dA
\end{equation}

where $q(x,y,z)$ is given by $\{q_j\}$ and $A$ by $\{A_j\}$. In this discrete case, it should read:

\begin{equation}
\overline{q}^* = \frac{\sum_{j=1}^N q_jA_j}{\sum_{j=1}^NA_j}
\end{equation}

With, in general, $q^*\neq \overline{q}^*$, the total power [W] on $A^*$ changes: $P^* = q^*A^*$ vs. $\overline{P}^*=\overline{q}^*A^*$.
This operation is then to be carried out for a second triangle with its neighbors and so on.
The total power $P_{tot}$ (no average) is simply given by the sum:

\begin{equation}
P_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^M P_i = \sum_{i=1}^M q_iA_i
\end{equation}

with $M$ being the total number of triangles (in the mesh). Instead:

\begin{equation}
\overline{P}_{tot} = \sum_{i=1}^M \overline{P}_i = \sum_{i=1}^M \overline{q}_iA_i
\end{equation}

This operation does not seems to be energy (equivalent to power here...) conservative, i.e. $P_{tot} \neq \overline{P}_{tot}$. In particular, I applied this operation to different cases and I always end up with:

\begin{equation}
P_{tot} < \overline{P}_{tot}
\end{equation}

I would like to have an explanation for such an effect since, being tied to the energy conservation, is a relevant topic. It can also be put on a more general ground: given a discrete set of variables, find a suitable surface average which guarantees the conservation of a macroscopic quantity.

Thank you very much in advance,

Matteo

Comment: How do you define an average $\bar{q}_i$ for only one triangle? The average you have is for over all of the triangles.

Comment: Hi Ninad, I evaluate the average on the set $\{\mathcal{T}_j\}$ with: (i) the reference triangle $\mathcal{T}^*$; (ii) the $(N-1)$ triangles which shares with the former one or more vertices. Hence, I have the area $A$ (i.e. the union of the areas of the $N$ triangles in the neighborhood) on which to integrate $q$ which takes the values $\{q_j\}$ (one for each triangle of the neighborhood). The average returns $\overline{q}^*$ which is assigned to $\mathcal{T}^*$ only. Then the process repeats: another reference triangle is chosen => neighbors => average => assignment and so on.